# Redis database storage limit and HA

Tags: redis, hiredis

I want to use redis server for my application which is having a large database. So i want to know how big data redis server can store ??? is it compatible for a large database as i have heard that redis is a in memory database

Answer (score 2):

Redis is an in-memory store. So the limit is the memory available on your box (or your boxes if you want to shard your data). Redis is extremely efficient because it mostly relies on O(1) or O(log n) algorithms, but this is at the cost of memory consumption.

If you plan to run a large database, it is probably not a good choice.

Comment: I heard that it also use virtual memory so that it can be scale for large databases. Is it true ??? If yes then how it works ?

Comment: It has never been extremely efficient, because Redis data structures are not adapted to virtual memory (not enough locality). It was deprecated in Redis 2.4, and removed in Redis 2.6. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is not a database for large data(said 30+GB of data), consider using SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), suitable for TBs of data, nearly all APIs of Redis.